# Workaround proxy to be able to call 32-bit dll

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I had a problem that I posted on StackOverflow about that I [could not connect to windows phone 7 from a 64-bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33561504/2021579). I got [one response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33720854/2021579) that said I should try to create a WCF Service over named pipe transport. Now, I have something that is working but since I am new to C#, WCF and COM, I would be happy for any good advice.

**BACKGROUND:**

I started with a 32-bit application that used a DLL that looked like below, everything worked fine in 32-bit but it did not work in 64 bit since it accessed the 32-bit ConMan2.dll.

Original WP7DLL (there are a lot of more functions than GetStatus, but that is not the important part):

```
namespace WP7DLL
{
    // Interface declaration.
    [Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111")]
    public interface IWP7DLL
    {
        int GetStatus();
        /* some more functions */
    };

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222")]
    public class WP7DLL : IWP7DLL
    {    
        public WP7DLL() { }

        public int GetStatus()
        {
             /* Line that gives an exception in 64 bit */
             MultiTargetingConnectivity connectivity = new MultiTargetingConnectivity(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
             /* Some code to get status from windows phone 7 */           
        }
   }
}
```

**MY SOLUTION:**
I moved all my functions from my dll and replaced with wrappers. My GetStatus is now placed in WCFService and is called WCFGetStatus.

New WP7DLL (compiled AnyCPU):

```
namespace WP7DLL
{
    public static class InteropShared
    {
        // Host signals it's ready and listening.
        public static readonly EventWaitHandle eventHostReady = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, @"eventHostReady");

        // Client asks the host to quit.
        public static readonly EventWaitHandle eventHostShouldStop = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, @"eventHostShouldStop");

        public const string pipeBaseAddress = @"net.pipe://localhost";

        /// <summary>Pipe name</summary>
        public const string pipeName = @"pipename";

        /// <summary>Base addresses for the hosted service.</summary>
        public static Uri baseAddress { get { return new Uri(pipeBaseAddress); } }

        /// <summary>Complete address of the named pipe endpoint.</summary>
        public static Uri endpointAddress { get { return new Uri(pipeBaseAddress + '/' + pipeName); } }

    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWP7Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int WCFGetStatus();
        /* some more functions */
    };

    // Interface declaration.
    [Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111")]
    public interface IWP7DLL
    {
        int GetStatus();
        /* some more functions */
    };

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222")]
    public class WP7DLL : IWP7DLL
    {

        private static int wp7dll_instances = 0;
        private static Process hostProcess;
        private static IWP7Service pipeProxy;
        private static object syncLock = new object();

        public WP7DLL()
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (wp7dll_instances == 0)
                {
                    /* Start the service */
                    hostProcess = new Process();
                    hostProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"\path\to\WCFService.exe";
                    hostProcess.Start();
                    InteropShared.eventHostReady.WaitOne();
                    pipeProxy = getPipeProxy();
                }
                wp7dll_instances++;
            }
        }
        ~WP7DLL()
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                wp7dll_instances--;
                if (wp7dll_instances == 0)
                {
                    /* Close WCFService.exe */
                    InteropShared.eventHostShouldStop.Set();
                    hostProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
        }
        public static IWP7Service getPipeProxy()
        {
            ChannelFactory<IWP7Service> pipeFactory =
              new ChannelFactory<IWP7Service>(
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(
                    InteropShared.endpointAddress));

            IWP7Service pipeProxy =
              pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            return pipeProxy;
        }
        public int GetStatus()
        {
            return (int)pipeProxy.WCFGetStatus();
        }
    }
}
```

WCFService (compiled x86):

```
using WP7DLL;

namespace WCFServer
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWP7Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int WCFGetStatus();
        /* some more functions */
    }
    public class WP7Service : IWP7Service
    {
        public int WCFGetStatus()
        {
             /* Line that gives an exception in 64 bit */
             MultiTargetingConnectivity connectivity = new MultiTargetingConnectivity(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
             /* Some code to get status from windows phone 7 */           
        }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
               typeof(WP7Service),
           new Uri(WP7DLL.InteropShared.pipeBaseAddress)))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWP7Service),
                  new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                  WP7DLL.InteropShared.pipeName);

                host.Open();

                /* Signal that the service is ready */
                WP7DLL.InteropShared.eventHostReady.Set();

                Console.WriteLine("Service is available!");

                /* Wait for signal to stop the service */
                WP7DLL.InteropShared.eventHostShouldStop.WaitOne();
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me those aren't the actual Guid's in production.

Comment: That is correct. I changed them, that might have been unnecessary. Sorry I was not clear.